# How to remote control using Droid VNC Server via USB?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, remote-access, vnc

I have installed [Droid VNC Server](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.onaips.vnc) on my Android phone 2.2 (CyanogenMod), but it is not clear how to control now my phone via USB.

When I start the server on the phone it gives me an IP but I cannot ping to it. I cannot neither connect using the browser at the specified address nor through VNC client.

I have root access.

Can someone explain me the steps to follow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no manual or FAQ I've found for the program so I'm not certain if this is the way they intended it to be used. It does work, though, and I can't see an alternative method of using USB.

1. You need ADB installed along with the proper drivers for your device. This varies with platform and phone, so check Google or XDA.
2. Enable USB Debugging on your device -- Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging
3. Plug in, start droid VNC server
4. On a command line, run these commands:

   - `adb forward tcp:5801 tcp:5801`
   - `adb forward tcp:5901 tcp:5901`
5. Visit http://localhost:5801 with a browser or point your VNC client to localhost:5901

I do notice that performance isn't any better over USB vs a 802.11g, so I'd only recommend going to the trouble of this if accessing your device via WiFi isn't feasible.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot! Only problem using browser it answer but show only two links to TightVNC and the author site. I use UltraVNC Viewer instead to connect and works very well.

Comment: You might not have Java installed, or the Java VNC client had some problem loading on your system. Either way, doesn't matter since UltraVNC worked for you.